# How can I disable incorrect shift key usage for better typing?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

In the pursuit of more efficient typing, I am trying to be more consistent about shift key I am using. Sometimes, I type a letter while shifting on the same side of the keyboard, while I would prefer to shift with the opposite shift key.

To break myself of this bad habit faster, I would like to only allow the shift key to capitalize letters on the opposite of the keyboard. Is there a way I can do this in Windows 10?